# Request Queue for League of Legends API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, queue

I am working on some website for League of Legends statistics, which uses the [RiotGames API](https://developer.riotgames.com/).

The API allows you to do a maximum amount of requests per 10 seconds, and another maximum amount of requests per 10 minutes.

I made several functions to realize a queue concept, where I pass the API requests into and which only pushs out as many requests as allowed and then waits until I can do more requests, based on the given limits.

Sidenote: The limits are applied to each API server individually (e.g. euw, na, oce, etc.)

I wonder how good my code is/where it could be improved:

```
var request = require("request");
var apiKey = "someAPIkey";
var constant10S = 3000;
var constant10M = 180000;
var requestQueue = {
    br: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    euw: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    eune: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    na: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    tr: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    kr: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    las: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    lan: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []},
    oce: {requests10S: 0, requests10M: 0, time10S: 0, time10M: 0, queueSleeping: true, requests: []}
};

function queuedRequest(server, urlDetail, parameter, callback) {
    if (typeof parameter === "function") {
        callback = parameter;
        parameter = {};
    }
    parameter.api_key = apiKey;
    var queries = "?";
    for (var query in parameter) {
        queries += query + "=" + parameter[query] + "&";
    }
    queries = queries.substring(0, queries.length - 1);
    var url = "https://" + server + ".api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + server + urlDetail + queries;
    var qR = {url: encodeURI(url), callback: callback, retry: 0};
    requestQueue[server].requests.push(qR);
    if (requestQueue[server].queueSleeping) {
        triggerQueue(server);
    }
}

function retryRequest(server, request) {
    requestQueue[server].requests.push(request);
    if (requestQueue[server].queueSleeping) {
        triggerQueue(server);
    }
}

function triggerQueue(server) {
    console.log("starting queue Worker...");
    requestQueue[server].queueSleeping = false;
    var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10S > 10000) {
        requestQueue[server].time10S = timeNow;
        requestQueue[server].requests10S = 0;
    }
    if (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10M > 600000) {
        requestQueue[server].time10M = timeNow;
        requestQueue[server].requests10M = 0;
    }
    queueWorker(server);
}

function queueWorker(server) {
    console.log("Current queue: " + requestQueue[server].requests.length);
    var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();
    if (requestQueue[server].requests10S >= constant10S && (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10S) < 10000) {
        console.log(server + " reached 10 seconds rate limit");
        setTimeout(function () {
            queueWorker(server)
        }, (10000 - (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10S)));
    } else if (requestQueue[server].requests10M >= constant10M && (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10M) < 600000) {
        console.log(server + " reached 10 minutes rate limit");
        setTimeout(function () {
            queueWorker(server)
        }, (600000 - (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10M)));
    } else {
        if (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10S > 10000) {
            requestQueue[server].time10S = timeNow;
            requestQueue[server].requests10S = 0;
        }
        if (timeNow - requestQueue[server].time10M > 600000) {
            requestQueue[server].time10M = timeNow;
            requestQueue[server].requests10M = 0;
        }
        requestQueue[server].requests10M++;
        requestQueue[server].requests10S++;
        var r = requestQueue[server].requests[0];
        console.log("working on request:" + r.url + " Retry: " + r.retry);
        requestQueue[server].requests.shift();
        request(r.url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (response != undefined) {
                if (response.statusCode === 404) {
                    body = "{}";
                }
            }
            if (error || response.statusCode === 429 || response.statusCode === 500 || response.statusCode === 503) {
                if (response) {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                }
                console.log(error);
                if (r.retry <= 5) {
                    r.retry++;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        retryRequest(server, r)
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    r.callback(error, response, body);
                }
            } else {
                r.callback(error, response, body);
            }
        });
        if (requestQueue[server].requests.length < 1) {
            requestQueue[server].queueSleeping = true;
        } else {
            queueWorker(server);
        }
    }
}
```